# Auto fill a column with formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create a basic Qty x Unit Price = Extended Price formula across 3 columns, where I can enter either the Unit Price or the Extended Price and the other will auto calculate. I have tried a basic VBA code as follows that reinserts the Unit Price formula if the entered price is deleted, but is throwing an error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("Unit_Rate")) Is Nothing Then
ElseIf Target = "" Then Range("Unit_Rate").Formula = "=N7/(1-M7)"
End If
End Sub
```

This resulted in "Runtime error 13, Type mismatch."

With virtually zero VBA knowledge, any help would be greatly appreciated please?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWAAC.png)

Comment: Is `Range("Unit_Rate")` a named range? If so, do you want the code be triggered if a change happens on this specific range? If so, you should use `If NOT Intersect(Target, Range("Unit_Rate")) Is Nothing Then`. Meaning that the intersection **creates a range**. But if the Target cell **contains a formula** and its value is supplied by that formula, **Change Event is not triggered**! You should use `Calculate` event. In a different way, it does not have a `Target` parameter...

Comment: Correct yes, it is a named range and triggered when something changes on that range.  I have now changed to `If NOT Intersect` and it now updates only when I delete something from the sheet.

Comment: This is exactly what I told you in the above comment. So, in which conditions do you want updating the formula? I can see that your formula does not refer a specific cell. It refers a neighbor cell. What happens when the "entered price is deleted"? Does it show an error?

Comment: My apologies.  It calculates only when I delete something from elsewhere in the sheet, but does not calculate when deleting something from within that range.
So, _What happens when the "entered price is deleted"?_ nothing happens and it does not show an error.  With my original code, it worked and also showed an error.

Comment: This only mean that you did not understand my suggestion...  The necessary condition should come immediately after the code line I suggested. `If NOT Intersect(Target, Range("Unit_Rate")) Is Nothing Then` `If Target.value = "" Then` `'do whatever you want` `End If` `End If`...

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help, I am attempting something beyond my knowledge.  The function of it now seems to be correct, but error as shown requires reset each time.  I Have added a screenshot to original question.

Comment: Do you manually change **a single cell**, as it should or **more than one**? If more, `Target.Value = ""` makes no sense... If more, are all of them empty (at least)?